# How to construct rule names according to an external factor?

Tags: shake-build-system

Till now i had the following code:

```
shakeArgsWith opts additionalFlags $ \flags targets -> return $ Just $ do
    ...
    -- Get target arch from command line flags
    let givenArch = listToMaybe [v | AFlag v <- flags]
    let arch = fromMaybe defArch givenArch
    ...
    -- Set the main target
    let outName = masterOutName projType toolchain projName

    let mainTgt = (case projType of
                    Binary _ -> "bin"
                    Archive  -> "lib")
                  </> prettyShowArch arch
                  </> show variant
                  </> outName

    -- Set the build directory for the current run
    let buildDir = bldDir </> show toolchain </> prettyShowArch arch </> show variant
    ...
    mainTgt %> \out -> do ...
    ...
    buildDir <//> "*.o" %> \out -> do ...
    ...
```

Meaning that the names of the rules where constructed according to a command line flag that i was parsing (they contained the arch variable).

So if i gave `shake --arch=x64` i was building the main target in `bin/x64/Release` directory and my intermidiate build files in the `tmp/x64/Release` folder accordingly.

But now instead of using the command line flag, i want the shared arch variable that is used to construct the rule names to be populated according to the output of some command, for example if i could define some top level action it would be this:

```
Stdout sout <- quietly $ cmd (EchoStdout False) (EchoStderr False) "gcc -dumpmachine" :: Action (Stdout String)
let foundArch = show (gccTripletToArch sout)
```

and use the variable foundArch instead of the arch when constructing the `mainTgt` and `buildDir` names. Obviously this cannot be done, as even the only top level rule that can be created with the `action` function returns `Rule ()`. What can i do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to do:

```
shakeArgsWith opts additionalFlags $ \flags targets -> do
     Stdout sout <- cmd (EchoStdout False) (EchoStderr False) "gcc -dumpmachine"
     let arch = show (gccTripletToArch sout)
     return $ Just $ do
         let buildDir = bldDir </> show toolchain </> prettyShowArch arch </> show variant
         ...
         buildDir <//> "*.o" %> \out -> do ...
```

The target patterns in Shake do have to be statically known, as that ensures some important properties with respect to quick rebuilding (you can guarantee a change in one place has predictable effects). However, you can run commands to determine things like arch, compiler version etc. *before* you create the build script, and bake them in.

Another viewpoint is that you are dynamically generated a build system based on the arch. Using Shake, as a Haskell EDSL, that is no particular problem, and you arguably were doing that before with the command line.

Comment: So i suppose that your answer is to detect the arch before i generate the build script (doing normal operations in main before shakeArgsWith)? The problem is that with your snippet i get
```Couldn't match expected type `IO (Stdout String)' with actual type `Action (Stdout String)'```.. I thought of doing the same thing too but with that solution i loose the power of the prebuilt Action functions that shake offers..

Comment: I removed the `quietly` - does it work now? `cmd` is flexible enough to be used in either `Action` or `IO`. When in `Action`, it does a few extra things, integrates with the Shake lint and profiling etc, but works just fine in IO too.

Comment: Well, obviously we need to remove the type specifier in the end (:: Action (Stdout String)) and it works! Will i have any excessive printing without quietly?

Comment: Thanks, now fixed - I need a wider monitor! The printing is part of the Action Monad instance for `cmd`, so won't happen with the `IO` version.